# Каким образом упрощается русский язык в диаспорах?

Tags: жаргон, социолингвистика

Каким образом упрощается русский язык в русских диаспорах (у носителей русского)?

То что он беднеет - обнаруживается "невооруженным ухом". Но помимо словарного запаса - что-то в грамматике может быть отлетает? Не могу сформулировать, в чем проблема того что слышу и чувствую.

Вопрос не тривиальный потому что в диаспорах употребление только устной русской речи свернуто. Чтение и письмо практикуется в полном объеме - рунет вне конкуренции. Это должно придавать явлению уникальности.

Ссылки приветствуются. Особенно на исследования, в которые включается "фактор рунета".

Comment: Об этом написаны целые труды, вот один из них: http://rus-jp.com/ruslanguage/articles/190-kazakevich3

Comment: Не вижу причин закрывать вопрос. Добавил к нему метку "запрос ссылок" и считаю, что ссылка на интересные источники будет хорошим ответом на такой вопрос.

Comment: @grizzly, это Ваша трактовка вопроса. Однако автор не запрос на ссылки прислал, а поставил очень общий вопрос, который предполагает широкую дискуссию, а это не соответствует задачам данного сайта.

Comment: вопрос подравлен. зайду в мету обсудить суть местного оффтопика.

Comment: У беты меты нету. Подскажу здесь - "общие вопросы в оригинальном SO закрываются не просто так (стали закрывать, раньше они были даже очень ontopic), а потому что они негативно влияют на экономику - происходит инфляция рейтинга - а за рейтниг там делают реальную работу (программируют). Нет смысла бороться за регуляцию экономики пока экономики нет. Всегда успеете закрыть. Тем более что все равно мой вопрос в нулях.

Comment: Роман, не понятно, почему вы считаете, что у «беты меты нету». Есть: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Буду знать. А почему: мою тропу замело. Через профайл обычно хожу, а там ссылки сейчас на профайл на мете нет.